# How to filter strings in pandas series index

Tags: python, filter, pandas, indexing, series

I'm trying to filter a pandas series by using a boolean expression on its index, which contains strings. For example, in the code below I wish to create a new Series (Sman) by filtering another series (S) for rows where the index items contain the substring 'man':

```
from pandas import Series
S = Series({'moondog':12,'catman':23, 'batman':31, 'catdog':42})
Sman = S['man' in S]
```

However, the result for Sman is simply the number 31, and not a new series containing the rows for 'catman' and 'batman' as I was hoping for.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) method:

```
In [11]: S.filter(like='man')
Out[11]:
batman    31
catman    23
dtype: int64
```

A manual alternative would be:

```
In [12]: S[['man' in i for i in S.index]]
Out[12]:
batman    31
catman    23
dtype: int64
```

The reason your approach did not work is that `'man' in S` just returns `False`, as this checks if the exact label 'man' is contained in the index (which is not the case).

Comment: Thanks Joris, both of your suggestions do indeed work. 
Surprisingly, the second manual alternative is 2.9x *faster* than the baked in 'filter' method.

Comment: But you were wrong about S['man' in S] returning False. It actually returns 31, which is the value associated with 'batman'

Comment: No, I meant that it is `'man' in S` that returns False, so you actually did `S[False]`, which I think returned the first value because it regards it as 0 (which is indeed 31 for batman if I run it). BTW, you should accept answers to mark your question as solved if that is the case (also for your other questions)

Comment: Ah yes, you're right Joris about the 'man' in S returning False. I bow to your greater wisdom, and thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks also for the prompt to accept the answer. I didn't realise that was part of the protocol. Actually, it took me a few minutes to figure out what you meant by 'accepting an answer' - Doh!